# Timed tcpdump: pipe is slow

Tags: linux, tcpdump, timeout

What I actually want to do is measure tcpdump for 10s.

```bsh
$ timeout 10s tcpdump > my.log
```

but I found there has only a short period actually being logged, instead of whole 10s.

therefore I did this experiment:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# a.sh
tcpdump & p1=$!

date                        
sleep 10s;                  
echo "Checkpoint #1"        
kill $p1;
```

```bsh
$ sudo ./a.sh # works as expected
$ sudo ./a.sh > my.log # not as expected
# it printed
25s
27s
27s
```

so it actually only logged 2s.

Q1: How to do what I want?

Q2: Why print into the terminal(or pts?) is faster than into files. (I guess it's the reason.)

Comment: `tcpdump` (formatted) output to a file may be buffered, and when `timeout` kills it, or your script does, anything still in the buffer is lost. Try `-l` (lower ell) or `-U` and maybe `--immediate-mode` also.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When its standard output is a tty, tcpdump turns on "immediate mode" (via `pcap_set_immediate_mode(3)`, on systems which support it) *and* (since tcpdump is using stdio functions for output) the output will be line buffered by default.

But when redirecting tcpdump's output to a file or pipe, you'll have to force *both* immediate mode and line buffering explicitly if you want the packets to be logged "live" into the file.

```
tcpdump --immediate-mode -l > my.log
```

You may also want to use the `-n` option, without which `tcpdump` would try to reverse lookup the addresses via DNS, which may take a lot of time.

```
tcpdump --immediate-mode -nl > my.log
```

---

When not using `tcpdump` interactively, it's much better to dump the raw packets with `-w` and parse them when reading the dump file with `-r`. In that case, `-U` should be used instead of `-l` if you want the dump output to be "live".

```
tcpdump --immediate-mode -Uw /path/to/dump
...
tail -c+0 -f /path/to/dump | tcpdump -r-
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's so detailed, really helped.